# google sheet vlookup a cell that do not contain multiple value

Tags: google-sheets

[How can I list all the buyer names who has not buy Prodct "Phone" or  Brand"Sony"  or  Seller" Ebay".   Thank you so much for your help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXLuJ.png)

Comment: We can't see the column letters or row numbers. And for us to solve it anyway, you are asking us to type in all of that information ourselves to our own sheet. Please share a link to your sample document, with the link's Share permission set to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." That is the fastest way to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your "Date" header is in A1:

`=FILTER(B2:B10, C2:C10<>"Phone", D2:D10<>"Sony", E2:E10<>"Ebay")`

It's a simple **[FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)**.

Comment: It works.  Thank you so much.   I really appreciate your help in resolving this.

Comment: Great! If you would, please take a moment to mark my post as "Best Answer" to close out this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Done.  Thanks again, my friend

Comment: Hi Erik, Could you help me with the question below? ------
          
Here is the my sample document link:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mNLx_yh8I_cmFnZYa-0aNUEnglk3n-qRnUUSq24kV70/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you so much.

Comment: @zongshita, it is not really how the forum works, to extend questions or to request specific help from one person. We are all volunteers here, and so we may not be available to help you. And the forum is designed to have each post represent one question only, so that future visitors can easily find answers (which will not happen if more questions and answers are buried in the Comments section of posts). I will leave a solution on your sheet with a note. But in the future, it's best to start a new post each time.

Comment: Thank you for your message.  I thought if post another similar question would violate the rules.    In the future, I will follow your advise.  Thanks a lot.